# Quit from the middle of password setting process

Tags: password, root, command-line

I try to check whether my root has password or not.

I run this command;

```
sudo passwd root
```

Later on it responses as;

```
Enter new UNIX password:
```

Based on that response, I have an indication that my root has no password.
Therefore I want to quit from the command process.

How can I do that, please?

Comment: Meanwhile, is my indication right?

Comment: BTW, I use Ubuntu Mini, so there is no option to quit from terminal by GUI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To view if your root has a password set use:

```
sudo passwd -S root
```

This will print out a:

1. `P` in the second column if it has a password;
2. `L` in the second column if it has a locked password (a password which is impossible to type in) and `L` is the default on Ubuntu;
3. `NP` if it has no password.

To get out of the new password dialog just type wrong passwords: Type a new password and when asked for confirmation for this new password type a different password. The passwords will not match and the program exits with an appropriate error message.

(You can't use signals to quit, because `passwd` ignores every signal. Except SIGKILL should work, but it is unnecessary and maybe insecure to use here.)

Answer (score 1):

> Based on that response, I have an indication that my root has no password.

No. Since your admin is the one changing the password the current password is not asked. Otherwise changing a password for an account would require asking the user for his/her password.

Check `/etc/shadow`. Those files tell you if a user has a password and what encryption is used.

The colums in `/etc/shadow` are :-seperated and indicate:

- User name : It is your login name
- Password: It your encrypted password. The password should be minimum 6-8 characters long including special characters/digits
- Last password change (lastchanged): Days since Jan 1, 1970 that password was last changed
- Minimum: The minimum number of days required between password changes i.e. the number of days left before the user is allowed to change his/her password
- Maximum: The maximum number of days the password is valid (after that user is forced to change his/her password)
- Warn : The number of days before password is to expire that user is warned that his/her password must be changed
- Inactive : The number of days after password expires that account is disabled
- Expire : days since Jan 1, 1970 that account is disabled i.e. an absolute date specifying when the login may no longer be used

===

See: http://linux.die.net/man/5/shadow If the password field contains some string that is not a valid result of crypt(3), for instance ! or *, the user will not be able to use a unix password to log in (but the user may log in the system by other means). ... **A password field which starts with a exclamation mark means that the password is locked. The remaining characters on the line represent the password field before the password was locked.**

===

> Therefore I want to quit from the command process.

control-x

It will show something like "[1]+  Stopped                 sudo passwd"

Comment: When I try to check `sudo pico /etc/shadow`, it gives me `root:!:16086:0:99999:7:::`. Does my root has password?

Comment: Yes but ! means the user is disabled as it should be on a system that uses sudo.

Answer (score 0):

To escape a command running in a bash terminal use `Ctrl-C`.